# Dynamic Form fields in `__init__` in Django admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, field

I want to be able to add fields to django admin form at runtime. My model and form:

```
#admin.py
class SitesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SitesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['mynewfield'] = forms.CharField()

class SitesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = SitesForm

admin.site.register(Sites,SitesAdmin)

#model.py
class Sites(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(u'URL')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True)
    is_new = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    group = models.ForeignKey('SitesGroup')
    config = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

Field `mynewfield` isn't displayed in form. Why?

Comment: I need to use ____init____ only

Comment: You should provide max_length in forms.CharField(), it might fail silently and also provide in ModelAdmin: class Meta: model = Sites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be adding a new field to your form in that way, you can just do it as you would any other field and the form will contain both the Model's original fields and your new fields:

```
class SitesForm(forms.ModelForm):
  mynewfield = forms.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

  class Meta:
    model = Sites

class SitesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = SitesForm

admin.site.register(Sites, SitesAdmin)
```

**Edit**: Sorry, should have read what you had written a little better. If you want a **dynamic** field like that, then you need to do the following and it will do exactly what you want:

```
class SitesForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Sites

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.base_fields['mynewfield'] = forms.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    super(SitesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class SitesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  form = SitesForm

admin.site.register(Sites, SitesAdmin)
```

It's the base_fields that gets composed by the metaclass that holds the fields that the form will use.

Comment: I know it, but I need to use __init__

Comment: That should do what you want now!

Answer (score 3):

Solution:

```
class AdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.insert(1, 'myfield', forms.CharField())

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AdminForm

    def get_fieldsets(self, request, obj=None):
        return (
            (None, {
                'fields': (..., 'myfield',),
            }),
        )
```